# Speech Recognition Library for OS X

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition

I'm literally going crazy to be able to run this library:
[libsprec](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec)

With the makefile for "os x" I created all files *.o* and the file *.dylib*.
The makefile has also copied created files to */usr/lib* and */usr/include*.
Now, after dragged the file .dylib in my project's frameworks, I have imported this header:

```
#import <sprec/sprec.h>
```

but Xcode say me:

```
> sprec.h not found
```

I don't have found any other library for speech recognition on OS X (NSSpeechRecognition doesn't make voice as string, but it find only predefined "commands").

What should I do?

Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: I'd answer this myself, but that code's author ( @H2C03 ) is actually [a very active participant here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3).

Comment: I spoke to him by email directly.
I should get rid of Xcode and start compiling in Terminal.
Before that, i would try to make the final attempt within Xcode with your help.

Comment: okay... I doubt you'll need my help but I'm always here.  :-)

Comment: If you want to help me (Thanks a lot :) ), we can talk via chat on Skype :)
What about?

Comment: haaa... I don't give out my Skype ID too easily, but you can usually find me parked at [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work

https://github.com/H2CO3/VocalKit

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Have you tried any of these?